# Simple clean CMS for programming project website

Tags: wordpress, drupal, content-management-system, themes

What is the best yet simple CMS for closed-source programming project hosting? I'd like to keep webpage plain and simple, include screenshot, basic features and blog headlines on main page, then have project blog, screenshots gallery, feature list and downloads on separate pages.

My goal is somethong between http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html , http://www.7-zip.org/ and http://winmerge.org/

Suitable themes for general-purpose CMSes are welcome too, but I'm affraid Wordpress or Drupal may too complex for such purposes. Or am I wrong? If I am wrong, please do not post "+1 for WP", but please link theme that meets requirements.

I'd like to host webpage on my own, so Google Code and similar does not fit.

Comment: Any particular language you'd like to avoid? I imagine if you don't find a something good out of the box, you'll want to do some tweaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good match for Wordpress. Wordpress is actually a decent small CMS not just a blogging engine.

Use Wordpress's static page feature to build your feature lists and download pages. Customize the home page template to show the information about your project, and move the blog articles to one side, showing only their headlines.

I can't recommend a theme offhand, but this would not be a hard thing to customize.

Comment: I'd like to state for the record that Wordpress is a pain in the ass to use as a proper CMS. The blog end is all well and good, but the second you involve new content or data types, you're in for a world of hurt.

Comment: True enough. But for most sites that only need one "news" content type, it's simple, clean, and extremely easy to use.

Comment: It is not at all a hard to customize CMS!

Answer (score 6):

Trac is commonly used for programming project websites. It has a great integration with source control and bug tracking, has a built-in Wiki and customizable styles to fit your aesthetic needs.

Answer (score 5):

Drupal is not too complex for what you want to do and is what I would recommend. You want themese? Drupal has [dozens](http://themegarden.org/drupal6/)  and [dozens](http://topdrupalthemes.net/)

Comment: Drupal also has the project module (http://drupal.org/project/project)

Comment: I also recommend Drupal.  It is clean, popular, and well-supported.

Comment: He asked for simple - Drupal has one of the worst admin interfaces of any CMS

Comment: @BlueRaja: I thought the same thing until I tried Drupal 7. Give it a go!

Answer (score 4):

I like to use Redmine with Subversion. Ive never tried to theme it or anything though. Its also a little complex but the complexity is actually geared toward maintaining projects as opposed to something like Drupal which is geared toward "content".

http://www.redmine.org/

Comment: Seconded, redmine is wonderful.

Comment: +1 for Redmine - I didn't find it difficult to setup or modify the themes. Everything is probably in the box ff you use the "news" section for the blog, although there specific plugins for a blog if required.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using [Bazzar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/) as version control system I would recommend you [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/).

Otherwise [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) will fit your requirements, but finding themes for it is difficult.

If you're hosting only one project, [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) will be easier to set up.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that If you wish to host a complete site as you have suggested, then MODx CMS will be a great alternative....

It is a very well featured CMS, with all webpage content being saved into a MySQL database... want to migrate your site... easy as.. Just copy the database and there you have it...

Modules include, blogging, newsletters + more!

Check it out at MODxcms.com and look up the features!

BTW... The community support forum is very, very helpful too!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using **[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)**.

Trac is a mix of a wiki and an issue tracking system, and with some theming, it will also make a perfect homepage. You can also extend it with plugins. For instance you could implement a project blog by using [blog plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracBlogPlugin).

I know Trac has some unappealing flavours, but if you really want to focus on your software, Trac is a really good way to put all related stuff in a same place.

Of course if you already have an internal project site / wiki, Trac is not a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite fond of sNews - http://www.snewscms.com/.

You can plug any basic template into it, all it needs is an index page and a css file.

Galleries aren't included by default, but here is a mod that adds them:

http://snewscms.com/forum/index.php?topic=8539.0

It's not too bloated or complex, and it's very easy to keep clean as it has a minimal set of features to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a service like CushyCMS (www.cushycms.com) which is very lightweight and has a free service. The only problem is that you have to go to their website and it displays their logos. But you can look at the priced options.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xp-dev.com is pretty cool, it's a  bit more then what you have asked for but it has all the features you want.

Answer (score 0):

Graffiti CMS is pretty easy to use, and is now free open source. You'd be able to create a theme like one of those examples by modifying a few theme files, which use nvelocity style markup.

http://graffiticms.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your self. But you could check out [www.opensourcecms.com](http://www.opensourcecms.com) where it describes the pros and cons of each cms and it also lets you see a **Demo** of each cms. It's the best place to decide.

Answer (score -1):

Sourceforge has it all. I'm positive it's what your looking for.

http://sourceforge.net/register/

Comment: not for closed-source app and - well - definitely not for surrent SF look'n'feel'n'usability...

Comment: Oh, guess I didn't realize you were close-sourcing it.